# perl - help with hash and dumping of records

Tags: perl, multidimensional-array, hash, hash-of-hashes

I have a perl script that is only keeping the last set of records for a named set and I have more than one set of records. So its over writing the data in the hash and just keeping the last set. I need help in printing out all the records.
Thanks!

Here's a copy of my script:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl 

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my ($ServerName)=@ARGV;
my %MyItems;
foreach my $ServerName(@ARGV){
   while (my $line = <>){
     chomp $line;
              if ($line =~ m/.* \w+ \d{2} (\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}) \d{4}: ([^:]+):backup:/){
                  my $ServerName = basename $ARGV, '.mydomain.com.backup-software.log'; #$ARGV is reading input from command line
                  my $BckupSet =$2;
                  my $BckupVal=$1;
                  $MyItems{$ServerName}{$BckupSet}->{'1-Server'}    = $ServerName;
                  $MyItems{$ServerName}{$BckupSet}->{'2-BackupSet'} = $BckupSet;
                  $MyItems{$ServerName}{$BckupSet}->{'3-StartTime'} = $BckupVal;

                  if ($line =~ m/(backup-date)[:=](.+)/){
                      my $BckupKey="4-DateStamp";
                      my $BckupVal=$2;
                      $MyItems{$ServerName}{$BckupSet}->{$BckupKey} = $BckupVal;
                  }

                  if ($line =~ m/(backup-time)[:=](.+)/){
                      my $BckupKey="5-Duration";
                      my $BckupVal=$2;
                      $MyItems{$ServerName}{$BckupSet}->{$BckupKey} = $BckupVal;
                  }
                  if ($line =~ m/(backup-size)[:=](.+)/){
                      my $BckupKey="6-Size";
                      my $BckupVal=$2;
                      $MyItems{$ServerName}{$BckupSet}->{$BckupKey} = $BckupVal;
                  }
                  if ($line =~ m/(Backup succeeded)/){
                      my $BckupKey="7-Status";
                      my $BckupVal="Succeeded";
                      $MyItems{$ServerName}{$BckupSet}->{$BckupKey} = $BckupVal;
                  }
                  if ($line =~ m/(ERROR)[:=](.+)/){
                      my $BckupKey="8-Status";
                      my $BckupVal="Unsuccessful";
                      $MyItems{$ServerName}{$BckupSet}->{$BckupKey} = $BckupVal;
                      print "$BckupKey=$BckupVal\n" if debug;
                  }
              }
   } #endwhile
   print Dumper(\%MyItems);
   for my $ServerName(keys%MyItems){
     for my $BckupSet(keys%{$MyItems{$ServerName}}){
       for(sort keys%{$MyItems{$ServerName}{$BckupSet}}){
         #print$_,'=>',$MyItems{$ServerName}{$BckupSet}{$_},';';
         print$_,'=',$MyItems{$ServerName}{$BckupSet}{$_},';';
       }
       print"\n";
     }
   }
} #END foreach
```

Here's what it looks like when it dumps:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'server1.name.colo' => { 
                                        'set1' => {
                                                               '3-StartTime' => '07:08:15',
                                                               '1-Server' => 'server1.name.colo',
                                                               '6-Size' => '72.04 GB',
                                                               '7-Status' => 'Succeeded',
                                                               '4-DateStamp' => '20100820060002',
                                                               '5-Duration' => '01:08:13',
                                                               '2-BackupSet' => 'set1',
                                                               '8-Status' => 'Unsuccessful'
                                                             },
                                        'set2' => {
                                                                '7-Status' => 'Succeeded',
                                                                '6-Size' => '187.24 GB',
                                                                '3-StartTime' => '01:51:25',
                                                                '4-DateStamp' => '20100820000003',
                                                                '1-Server' => 'server1.name.colo',
                                                                '5-Duration' => '01:51:21',
                                                                '2-BackupSet' => 'set2'
                                                              },
                                        'set3' => {
                                                              '3-StartTime' => '23:00:05',
                                                              '4-DateStamp' => '20100814230003',
                                                              '1-Server' => 'server1.name.colo',
                                                              '8-Status' => 'Unsuccessful',
                                                              '2-BackupSet' => 'set3'
                                                            },
                                        'set4' => {
                                                              '7-Status' => 'Succeeded',
                                                              '6-Size' => '427.75 GB',
                                                              '3-StartTime' => '00:43:20',
                                                              '4-DateStamp' => '20100819200004',
                                                              '1-Server' => 'server1.name.colo',
                                                              '5-Duration' => '04:43:14',
                                                              '2-BackupSet' => 'set4'
                                                            },
                                        'set3' => {
                                                              '7-Status' => 'Succeeded',
                                                              '6-Size' => '46.42 GB',
                                                              '3-StartTime' => '04:42:59',
                                                              '4-DateStamp' => '20100820040002',
                                                              '1-Server' => 'server1.name.colo',
                                                              '5-Duration' => '00:42:56',
                                                              '2-BackupSet' => 'set3'
                                                            }
                                      }
        };
```

Comment: what exactly are you expecting to see?  more than 1 server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the debug output, it looks like your problem is here:

```
if ($line =~ m/(ERROR)[:=](.+)/){
    my $BckupKey="8-Status";
    my $BckupVal="Unsuccessful";
    $MyItems{$ServerName}{$BckupSet}->{$BckupKey} = $BckupVal;
    print "$BckupKey=$BckupVal\n" if debug;
}
```

To save all errors, you'll need to treat that hash slot as a reference to an array:

```
if ($line =~ m/(ERROR)[:=](.+)/){
    my $BckupKey="8-Status";
    my $BckupVal="Unsuccessful";
    push @{ $MyItems{$ServerName}{$BckupSet}{$BckupKey} } => $BckupVal;
    print "$BckupKey=$BckupVal\n" if debug;
}
```

In your dump, the `8-Status` values will resemble

```
'8-Status' => [ 'Unsuccessful', 'Other error', 'Et cetera' ],
```

If you want to loop over them later, you'd do something like

```
foreach my $err (@{ $MyItems{$ServerName}{$BckupSet}{$BckupKey} }) {
    print "got $err\n";
}
```

To get only the first, you'd write

```
print $MyItems{$ServerName}{$BckupSet}{$BckupKey}[0], "\n";
```

Another issue is

```
foreach my $ServerName(@ARGV){
   while (my $line = <>){
```

Realize that `while (<>) { ... }` implicitly loops over all files named in `@ARGV`, so nesting it inside a loop over `@ARGV` doesn't quite make sense. If your command line is of the form

```
$ readlogs server1 server2 server3 log1 log2
```

then you'd want to first remove from `@ARGV` the servers using [`shift`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shift.html). Distinguishing arguments the user intends as server hostnames could be tricky. One convention is using `--` to signal the end of option processing, so you might

```
my @servers;
while (@ARGV) {
  my $server = shift;
  last if $server eq "--"
  push @servers => $server;
}

die "Usage: $0 server .. -- log ..\n" unless @ARGV;

while (<>) {
  # ...
}
```

Comment: thank you. would i apply the push to all my other if conditions as well? printing the keys too?

Comment: @jda6one9 Using `push` for all of them would work, but you may get annoyed with one-element arrays. Doing it this way has the advantage of never throwing away data, but it may be too permissive for what you want to do.

Comment: you helped me earlier with using this --> xargs -I{} ./myscript.pl {} <prodlogs.txt   Where 'prodlogs.txt' is a list of all there server logs I need to scan. Anyways, i will definitely take note of your input. thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

This is off topic, but any time you need deeply nested data structures your code runs a risk of becoming bloated and hard to read. Simple convenience variables go a long way toward streamlining things and relieving the reader of the code (you, 3 months from now) of having to perform many mental diffs:

```
# A convenience var.
my $bs = $MyItems{$ServerName}{$BckupSet};

# The rest of your code can use the var.
$bs->{'1-Server'} = $ServerName;
```

Also, you've got several `if` blocks that do basically the same thing. Seems amenable to some sort of dispatch table strategy:

```
my @dispatch_table = (
    {
        regex => qr/(backup-date)[:=](.+)/,
        key   => '4-DateStamp',
        val   => sub { $2 },
    },
    {
        # etc.
    },
);
```

Then your `if` blocks boil down to something like this:

```
for my $dt (@dispatch_table){
    next unless $line =~ $dt->{regex};
    $bs->{ $dt->{key} } = $dt->{val}->();
}
```

Comment: @FM - thanks for the tips! I've basically learned perl in the last few weeks. So, I'll take what I can get as far as learning.